# Gun doesn't stay relative to camera in a desirable way

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

In my hierarchy, I have my gun as a child to my camera. As you can tell from the pictures the gun appears to float in the air upon moving the camera up. How can I make the gun relative to the camera so that it sticks to the camera however I position it in the inspector?

I don't want it to look like this

[image]

I want it to look like this, even when rotating the camera up.

[image]

Comment: Have you fried adjusting your FOV (Field of View) on your camera?

Comment: @ApolloSoftware yes, same thing happens

Comment: So you want the camera to look up with the Gun in the same rotation, perpendicular to the plane?

Comment: @ApolloSoftware yes. I want the gun to be in the exact position on the screen no matter which way i rotate the camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of search, I ended up figuring it out by myself. The parent object the camera was connected to wasn't a uniform shape thus skewing the gun's shape when rotating the camera. I simply set the scale of the parent object to 1,1,1 and it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach to your Gun Object a script that does:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {
    public Quaternion x;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        x = transform.rotation;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.rotation = x;
    }
}
```

From what I understand you want the Gun to remain a child but you want to "lock" rotation. This script would retain the Rotation of the gun, and while also letting you translate the location without locking that.

Store the rotation initially as a Quaternion during Start, then when Update is called every frame, it'll set the rotation to the initial Quaternion.

In the future if you want to break the Rotation to individual x, y, z, you can lock certain axes with transform.rotation.x, y, z and store each individually as floating point variables.